# COOP and COEP: Is there an advantage to enabling COOP / COEP if I don't need to use the sharedArrayBuffer or other features?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, spectre, crossdomain

COOP: cross origin opener policy

COEP: Cross origin embedder policy

Most of the articles on the web, related to COOP / COEP, point to the fact that by enabling COOP / COEP , your web page can use the sharedArrayBuffer and some other precision timer related functions.

I understand that there is a bigger concept of cross origin isolation which is connected to this, but in the current implementation, are there any other benefits of enabling COOP / COEP apart from allowing the web page to use these functionality ?

These are the things I already understand:

- Cross origin isolation prevents against attacks like spectre which use the same process memory by using precision timers.
- COOP: same-origin would mean that no other cross origin window would have a reference to your window, the parent window that opened your page, or the child window that your page opens. This seems like it would impact cross window communication with postMessage
- COEP: require-corp would mean that any cross origin resources like images (which are generally exemptron CORS) would need to opt in, so that your page is allowed to load them

I am unable to understand what are the bigger implications of cross origin isolation. are all of the above side effects of cross origin isolation or are they intended effects ?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct, but COOP/COEP are only partial solutions.

In a post-Spectre world, we want to avoid sharing a browser process with a potential attacker.

> Sometimes, multiple documents from different sites can end up sharing a process in Chrome. This can happen when one has opened the other using `window.open`, or `<a href="..." target="_blank">`, or `iframe`s. If a website contains user-specific data, there is a chance that another site could use these new vulnerabilities to read that user data.
>
> — [Chrome Developers – Meltdown/Spectre](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/meltdown-spectre/#the-risk)

COOP: same-origin prevents other origins to share a browsing context group with your window through `window.open` or `target="_blank"` links without `rel="noopener"`, regardless if they're in a parent or a child situation.

> The `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` header provides a way for a document to isolate itself from cross-origin windows opened through `window.open()` or a link with `target="_blank"` without `rel="noopener"`. As a result, any cross-origin opener of the document will have no reference to it and will not be able to interact with it.
>
> — [web.dev – Security headers quick reference](https://web.dev/security-headers/#coop)

An interesting thing to note though is that COOP doesn't affect `iframe`s:

> Because COOP is defined in terms of browsing context groups, it doesn't apply to iframes; the browser ignores COOP on documents which aren't top-level, and allows iframes to access their cross-origin ancestors even if these ancestors set COOP.
>
> [...]
>
> With this COOP the browser can ensure that, **with the exception of frames**, no cross-origin documents are present in the same browsing context group / process as the current document.
>
> — [COOP and COEP explaned](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zDlfvfTJ_9e8Jdc8ehuV4zMEu9ySMCiTGMS9y0GU92k/edit)

On the COOP page on XS-Leaks Wiki they also highlight the fact it's a complement to framing protection:

> Getting access to a website’s `window` object is a common prerequisite for different XS-Leak techniques. Framing Protections can ensure that an attacker cannot use `iframe`s to access the `window` object, but this does not stop an attacker from accessing the `window` object from an opened window through `window.open(url)` or `window.opener` references.
>
> — [XS Leaks Wiki – Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy](https://xsleaks.dev/docs/defenses/opt-in/coop/)

This is why we also need to set `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` (or `DENY`). Even if you use `COEP: require-corp`, `COOP: same-orgin` and `CORP: same-origin`, you can still be embedded in an `iframe` if you don't set `X-Frame-Options`. You can test this in [this demo](https://first-party-test.glitch.me/). Not setting `X-Frame-Options` could leave you vulnerable to Spectre-like attacks in browsers that don't support [out-of-process `iframe`s](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes/).

As you pointed out, COEP only prevents *you* to include cross-origin resources that didn't explicitly opt in to it.

> `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` protects the origin from attackers
> `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` protects victims from the origin
>
> — InfoQ – COOP and COEP

This is why APIs that expose high precision timers are only available when COEP is enabled. Because you can perform Spectre-like attacks with those APIs, it makes sure that you can only attack resources that you have explicit permission to embed, limiting the attack surface quite a lot.

If you don't need those APIs, there's little benefit to enable COEP. If an attacker includes arbitrary resources on your site (for example through an XSS), COEP could prevent those resources to load, but in practice an attacker would likely want to include resources that *they* control, and where they can set `CORP: cross-origin` anyways.

To sum up, here's what both the W3C and Chrome recommend to mitigate Spectre-like attacks:

> 1. **Decide when (not!) to respond to requests** by examining incoming headers, paying special attention to the `Origin` header on the one hand, and various `Sec-Fetch-` prefixed headers on the other.
> 2. **Restrict attackers' ability to load your data as a subresource** by setting a cross-origin resource policy (CORP) of `same-origin` (opening up to `same-site` or `cross-origin` only when necessary).
> 3. **Restrict attackers' ability to frame your data as a document** by opt-ing into framing protections via `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` or CSP's more granular frame-ancestors directive (`frame-ancestors 'self' https://trusted.embedder`, for example).
> 4. **Restrict attackers' ability to obtain a handle to your window** by setting a cross-origin opener policy (COOP). In the best case, you can default to a restrictive `same-origin` value, opening up to `same-origin-allow-popups` or `unsafe-none` only if necessary.
> 5. **Prevent MIME-type confusion attacks** and increase the robustness of passive defenses like cross-origin read blocking (CORB) / opaque response blocking (ORB) by setting correct `Content-Type` headers, and globally asserting `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`.
>
> — [W3C – Post-Spectre Web Development](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-post-spectre-webdev/#tldr)
> — [Chromium Blog -  Mitigating Side-Channel Attacks](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/mitigating-side-channel-attacks.html)